# GUI interaction

Tags: windows, button, user-interface, textbox

I am trying to write a program/script but I am not able to find a coding language (out of many) which would allow me to perform the tasks I want it to do.

I am aware of the fact that there are perhaps numerous coding languages which would allow me to do so, therefore, to make this question a bit more specific: 'Which coding language would **you** recommend a beginner to write a program which will be able to perform the following tasks (see below)?

1. Read some variables from a local HTML page
2. Fill in this variable in a textbox in a running application/program
3. Click a predetermined button
4. Loop the above mentioned on some predetermined condition (i.e. whether the variable has changed).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your programming background, for which platform you are developing application. For windows C# will be good option, java is also another option.

Comment: I am developing for Windows, so C# should be able to this?